# Retrieve data from form html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text

**Hi all i have this 3 forms:**

```
<label for="color1" style="color: yellow;">1° colore:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="color1" placeholder="Insert color">

<label for="color2" style="color: yellow;">2° colore:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="color2" placeholder="Insert color">

<label for="result" style="color: red;">Risultato:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="result" >
```

**and a button**

```
<button type="button" onclick="merge()">merge</button>
```

Now i want that the function merge() takes the text inserted in the first 2 forms and put the append of the 2 string in the 3rd form.

i tried something like:

```
<script>
function merge(){
    var r1= $('#idform1').val();
    var r2= $('#idform2').val();
    $('#idform3').val('r1+r2');}
</script>
```

idform1 , idform2 and idform3 are not the correct id's but it's just to be more clear.
Of course it's not working , can anyone help me out ? thanks

Comment: Try `$('#idform3').val(r1+r2);` instead of `$('#idform3').val('r1+r2');`

Answer (score 2):

replace your code with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="put your path to jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<label for="color1" style="color: yellow;">1° colore:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="color1" placeholder="Insert color">

<label for="color2" style="color: yellow;">2° colore:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="color2" placeholder="Insert color">

<label for="result" style="color: red;">Risultato:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="result" >
<button type="button" onclick="merge()">merge</button>
<script>
function merge(){ 
    var r1= $('#color1').val();
    var r2= $('#color2').val();
    $('#result').val(r1+r2);}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You realise there was already an id (`result`) on that third element, you've added a second id attribute (`color3`)

Answer (score 0):

You got every thing Just change this

```
<script>
function merge(){
    var r1= $('#idform1').val();
    var r2= $('#idform2').val();
    $('#idform3').val('r1+r2');}// this line
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
function merge(){
    var r1= $('#idform1').val();
    var r2= $('#idform2').val();
    $('#result').val(r1+r2);}// to this
</script>
```

and if you have for more specification you can use `String(yourValue)` function like this `$('#result').val(String(r1)+String(r2))` but here we don't really need this.

Comment: `r1` and `r2` are already strings, why would you need to cast them to a string?

Comment: i know i mention that as you can see "but here we don't really need this." its for different scenario and for extra knowledge .

Comment: Then you forgot to mention that you should tighten the bolts on your wheels when you change a tyre (also irrelevant to the question - but extra knowledge nonetheless!)

Answer (score 0):

first you know you use wrong input tag id change correct ids then change `val("r1+r2")` to `val(r1+r2)`. if you use variable there not **string `" "` quote** String Quote only for when normal text you set.

and finally you use jQuery under JavaScript so add in Head tag jQuery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

here your full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function merge(){
    var r1= $('#color1').val();
    var r2= $('#color2').val();
    $('#result').val(r1+r2);}
</script>
</body>
<label for="color1" style="color: yellow;">1° colore:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="color1" placeholder="Insert color">
<br>
<label for="color2" style="color: yellow;">2° colore:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="color2" placeholder="Insert color">
<br>
<label for="result" style="color: red;" >Risultato:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="result" >
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="merge()">merge</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed the everything you said , i inserted the jquery libray and omittetd the "" on val.(r1+r2) but still nothing happen when i press the button , i'm working with intel XDK

Comment: @nescionomen93 you check my code it's work. can you please paste your full original code so debug any other issue there. 
this is for what you asked for it's working well